# Find out which friends I already have

Tags: dust-an-elysian-tail

I've been enjoying the game Dust: An Elysian Tail for PS4.

The trophy I'm trying to get is called [Baker's Dozen](http://www.truetrophies.com/t90759/bakers-dozen-trophy.htm)

There's a video showing where each one is. I've beat the game so I'm pretty sure that I have a majority of these "friends" but I was wondering if there's a way to tell *which* friends I've already acquired and which ones I still need to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, but you'll need to actively work for it.

Simply go to the *Sanctuary* on the world map and enter the room in which your trophy will pop up if you have saved all 12 friends.

There, you will be able to see every friend you have saved so far. Compare the ones you already have with the ones in this video:

If the video is no longer available, you can always Google a list of friends and perform an image search for that particular character. All friends are characters from another game.

#### EDIT:

If you see a duck that looks nothing like the characters at the beginning of the video, that's one of the Hyperducks. The one from *Aurora Village* wears a purple vest, while the other from *Abadis Forest* wears a red one. Once you've saved the both of them, they'll wear the blue suit and the high-tech helmets as seen at the beginning of the video.

Comment: Strangely i have a couple creatures that are not specified in this video, for example a donald duck looking friend. Perhaps this is a different version or something.

Comment: @SSHThis, the Donald-like friend is one of the Hyperducks. They only look like what you see in 0:00 once you've saved both of them. The one in *Aurora Village* wears a purple vest, while the one in *Abadis Forest* wears a red one. Once you rescue both, they'll wear a blue suit and Daft Punk-like helmets.